# Can I create a user account on OS X that has a whitelist of accessible urls?

Tags: macos

I'd like to block the entire internet except for specific sites like stackoverflow in order to stay productive.

I know about browser plugins that do this but then I will simply cheat by switching to another browser or using the one running in my Windows VM. I know that I can blacklist urls by redirecting them to 0.0.0.0 in the /etc/hosts, but I'm looking to whitelist. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Mac OS X 10.3 or later, you can use the built in Parental Controls to create an Internet whitelist.

To enable it, choose Parental Controls from the System Preferences menu of an Administrator account, activate it for the user account you want the whitelist on, and choose the "Allow access to only these websites" filter in the Content tab.

For more in-depth information on Parental Controls Internet content filtering, check out the Apple Support page [HERE](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2900).

Comment: Thank you! I don't have reputation to vote you up unfortunately.